# Merge main paper and supplementary on Overleaf

Tags: multicolumn, overleaf

I've a 2-column main paper with tex files and subfolders, and I have a 1-column (full width) supplementary to that paper but created as a separate project with its own tex files and subfolders.

I want to merge the two. After the main paper ends, the supplementary should begin, with a new title. For example, if "X" is the title of the paper, then after the paper and the bibliography, "Supplementary for X" should come after that, and then the contents of the supplementary in 1 column (wide).

If it helps, both main paper and supplementary use the ICCV templates. My paper got rejected and I need to upload both to arxiv, but I'm unable to merge the main paper with supplementary.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If it's just about merging two files, I would consider external tools, such as http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/ and work just with the pdfs.

Another option would be to `\input` the SI source file to the main paper, but since you have two separate projects, I think it can't be done directly in Overleaf.